# Google App Engine: Correctly configuring a static site with advanced routing

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2, google-cloud-platform, app.yaml

I've spent several shameful hours trying to solve this to no avail...

**Problem:**

I have a static website I am developing that is 100% pre-processed via Grunt & Assemble (if you are familiar with Jekyll, it is essentially the same concept). It also has a simple static Blog component which houses category directories of various names. As such, I need the catch-all in my app.yaml to route them appropriately.

However, I also would also like to have a custom error page to show in place of the standard GAE page status.

It seems that you cannot accomplish accounting for both scenarios in app.yaml alone because you can only use the catch-all target once.

Here is the logic in my current app.yaml

```
- url: (.*)/
  static_files: dist\1/index.html
  upload: dist/index.html
  expiration: "15m"

- url: /(.*)
  static_files: dist/\1/index.html
  upload: dist/(.*)/index.html
  expiration: "15m"
```

This is perfect for my use case because it routes any path to an index file if it exists in the current directory. However, because it uses the catch-all, I cannot again use it for something like the following

```
- url: /(.*)
  static_files: custom_error.html
```

or depend on

```
error_handlers:
  - file: custom_error.html
```

because it only renders for paths with no matching url pattern...

**Ideas:**

My next thoughts were that I may be able to accomplish this with some advanced routing via an external Python script

```
- url: /.*
  script: main.app
```

but after trying a myriad of various setups I have yet to stumble onto a way to accomplish this.

One example of a trail of breadcrumbs I was on would be

```
import os
import webapp2
import jinja2

# vars
jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader('jinja'), extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'], autoescape=True)

class mainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        if (an-index-file-exists-in-this-directory)
            # follow the same static file logic as the app.yaml
            # static_files: dist/\1/index.html
            # upload: dist/(.*)/index.html
        else:
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('404/index.html')
            context =  {
                'page_title': '404',
            }
            self.response.out.write(template.render(context))
            self.error(404)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/.*', mainHandler)
], debug=False)
```

I'm not even sure if taking it into an external python file would help solve the issue or not, but this was my awkward stab at it.

Does anyone have any ideas on how you can achieve custom error pages when your catch-all pattern is being used for another important purpose?

### Update: Solved

Ok I finally have this figured out, but because Stack Overflow thinks I'm not cool enough to answer my own question (low point threshold?), I've posted the solution here:

https://gist.github.com/dustintheweb/c5e6e4ee1a64d50d7f87

Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Anthuin's answer points out, you can't **write** (nor modify) those `index.html` files on disk (nor create new ones dynamically), so it makes little sense to try to **read** them from disk -- the "disk" available to GAE apps is read-only (and split between the part only available for static serving, and the part readable by the app code itself).

Rather, unless the `index.html` files are huge (unlikely, I suspect), I'd keep them in the GAE **datastore** for your app.  A really simple model:

```
from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Indx(ndb.Model):
    body = ndb.TextProperty()
```

assuming the path is no longer than 500 characters and the body up to a megabyte.  Then, your `MainHandler` becomes pretty simple:

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        key = ndb.Key('Indx', self.request.path)
        ent = key.get()
        if ent:
            self.response.write(ent.body)
        else:
            # your existing 404-returning code goes here
```

The `app.yaml` routing `/.*` to this script, and your `app =` code, need no change.

Now, the only thing that remains is, how did you expect to write, or modify, these `index.html` files (now datastore entities)?  I have no idea because as long as they **were** to be files your app couldn't possibly have written nor modified them.  In any case, now that they're in the data store, the writing also becomes very simple:

```
def write_indx(path, body):
    ent = Indx(body=body, id=path)
    ent.put()
```

Note that there is no real "modify" -- to possibly "modify" some `index.html`'s "body", you'll actually read the previous one, make a new `body` string, and rewrite the entity with the above `write_indx`.

Potential problems include: bodies of more than 1 MB; and, keys (paths) of more than 500 characters.  The former can easily be worked around by using, as @Anhuin suggested, Google Cloud Storage instead of the GAE datastore; the latter may perhaps be a problem because even GCS object names have limits (differently from GCS object lengths) -- specifically, 1024 bytes once the name is converted into utf-8.  Is either of these issues likely to be a problem for you?  If so, let us know!

Comment: So yeah, to clarify, I'm not using GAE in a traditional sense here, merely think of it as web hosting for a bunch of pre-processed static files (assembled locally via Grunt etc, then pushed up to be hosted). I'll give this a whirl & report back - thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, I was not able to get this to work. After deploy / page refresh I just get a default server error & the app engine logs do not show an exception. Here's my code, am I missing something? app.yaml : http://pastebin.com/ftVFc23r --- main.py : http://pastebin.com/haEN6vrn

Comment: Also, in case I was unclear in some way, the core of this app is just a static site that will only update per deploy. It will have various small dynamic pieces, but they are external components.

Comment: Ok scratch that ^ user error on my part (blasted indent errors!). So running it through it still seems to not be working as intended (page loads but it just shoots to the error template). I traced it back to ent pulling a value of none. Any thoughts?

Comment: @dustintheweb, where/when are you writing the Indx entities?  Check the console to see what's actually in your datastore -- of course it will be empty if you never put anything there (and then the `key.get` will always return `None`).

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this - your solution got me thinking on the right path & I ended up finding something that worked for me - updated in OP. Email me a bitcoin address and I'll buy you lunch (myusername@gmail.com) - thx again

Comment: @dustintheweb, always HTH -- I don't do bitcoin, but why not instead accept this answer (click on the checkmark outline to the left of it)?-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can make your first solution work like that, because as you said it will match every pattern and the error handler will never match.

And unless you plan to deploy your app each time you have a new blog post to add, I don't think having a static handler is a working solution anyway because you cannot upload content directly in your static app folder.

But you can upload content to GCS (for example) and retrieve it from a WSGIApplication.

Then this WSGIApplication can have a custom error handler:

```
def handle_404(request, response, exception):
   response.write("my custom error 404")

app.error_handlers[404] = handle_404
```

You just raise a 404 if the template isn't found and this handler will get called.

Comment: This definitely works as far as generating a custom error / template, but if I am changing the app.yaml catch-all to load a python script, then I will need to come up with a way in python to mimic what it was doing for me and put it in a condition. Thats where I am stumped in the 2nd example above :/

Comment: Where do you want to store your blog posts ?
That's the part I don't understand, why do you need this generic static handler ?

Comment: It's a static site (think jekyll or assemble), so they are just individual index.html files - a one-to-one match for each path. So /blog references /blog/index.html, /blog/foo/bar/this-is-a-post references /blog/foo/bar/this-is-a-post/index.html -- and so forth